# Making a list with corresponding image

Tags: python, tkinter

i am trying to make a programme where it will print a random data from a list with a corresponding image but it is giving me an error like

```
> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "C:\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)   File "c:\Users\Fahima\Desktop\importing.py", line 24, in fun
>     top.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(absolute_path.strip()+anime[random_choice]))
> File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2904, in open
>     fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb") FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'C:\\Users\\Fahima\\Desktop\\imagesnaruto.jpeg'
```

here is my code

```
 import random 
from tkinter import*
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

absolute_path = r'C:\Users\Fahima\Desktop\images' # your absolute path goes here(Note: Don't remove the extra space in the end) 

anime = {
"1 Naruto": 'naruto.jpeg' # anime image name
}

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")

def fun():

    top = Toplevel(root)
    top.title('Anime')

    random_choice = random.choice(list(anime.keys())) #choosing random from dictionary keys
    
    label = Label(top, text=random_choice)
    label.pack()

    top.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(absolute_path.strip()+anime[random_choice]))
    
    image_label = Label(top, image=top.img)
    image_label.pack()

can = Canvas(root, height = 100, width = 100)
can.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

b1 = Button(can,text = "Generate",command = fun,activeforeground = "black",activebackground = "yellow",pady=10)
b1.pack(side = TOP)

root.mainloop()
```

for the test i put only one data in the list
[here is the image absolute path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvYbK.png)

Comment: A path separator is missing between the path and the filename.  Use `absolute_path = r'C:\Users\Fahima\Desktop\images\' instead.

Comment: As @acw1668 suggested you need to add a backslash at the end also don't forget about the extra space in the end.  so your path should be `r'C:\Users\Fahima\Desktop\images\ ' `

Comment: @JacksonPro What is the purpose of the space at the end?

Comment: @scotty3785 otherwise the editor will throw an invalid syntax error.

Comment: @JacksonPro I guess that's another good reason to use os.path.join or Pathlib to join file parts. I never end my folder paths with `\` or `/` and leave the correct library to deal with correctly joining them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a path separator between the directory and file name if you read the error message `'C:\\Users\\Fahima\\Desktop\\imagesnaruto.jpeg'`

Try using

```
top.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(os.path.join(absolute_path.strip(),anime[random_choice])))
```

This should correctly join the path together with the correct path separator.